Anthropic bound on the neutron eDM
My question is fairly simple. What's the best upper bound that we can set on the neutron's eDM just based on anthropic arguments, i.e., on the basic fact that atoms, molecules (and humans!), do form?

I presume that having a dipole moment would alter the energetics of nuclear binding, but my nuclear physics is not not up to putting any bounds on that.

@JonCuster Even when I was getting my PhD in nuke fizz, my skills would not be up to it, but even in an alpha particle, the proton repulsion is small compared with the strong force. I would expect the bigger problem would be related to massive parity violation required for an eDM would have an effect somewhere else.

I voted to close as opinion based because I don't think anyone could offer more than an opinion on this.  It's a long way from a simple question.

@StephenG-HelpUkraine I mean, "offering" a well reasoned upper bound wouldn't be an opinion. For example, using Jon Custer's answer, we could say that the eDM can't be more than X, where X is enought so that the EM energy in an atom (let's say one with 2 neutrons) is comparable to that of the strong force.

As an extra, I think that Schwartz's problem 11.10 c) is similar to this, as he asks "Why is it OK for a molecule (such as H2O) or a battery to have an EDM but not the neutron (which is made up of quarks with different charges)?".
